# Change object in a list

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>();
test.Add(new Foo(2));
List<Foo> test2 = new List<Foo>();
test2.Add(test[0]);
test2[0] = new Foo(3);
```

When I assign a new object to `test2[0]`, `test[0]` does *not* change. How can I change `test[0]` through `test2[0]`?

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I already have two objects. In the end I want to change the first object to be the second object.

```
Foo bar0 = new Foo(2);
Foo bar1 = new Foo(3);
List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>();
test.Add(bar0);
List<Foo> test2 = new List<Foo>();
test2.Add(test[0]);
// now what?
```

Comment: If you edit the object instead of replacing it, it will do what you're thinking.

Comment: The simplest way is to just do `List<Foo> test2 = test`. Though whether it is what you may actually need, I don't know.

Comment: @Vlad274: I want to replace the object however.

Comment: _"How can I change test[0] through test2[0]"_ You can't.  This smells of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you explain more about what actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @gartenriese obviously I don't know the full situation you're in, but conceptually if you have two references to the same object and want to replace both references, you're probably just trying to change the object. Perhaps you should have a method on Foo that takes in all the values you need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
test2[0] = new Foo(3);
```

You're not modifying the object at `test2[0]`, you're modifying `test2` itself.  And the modification you're making is that you're putting a new object at a specific index.

This doesn't do anything to the object that used to be there.  Nor should it.

If you want to modify the object that's there, you can modify it directly:

```
test2[0].SomeProperty = someValue;
```

Conversely, if you want `test2` and `test` to be the same collection (so that modifying one also modifies the other), then make them the same collection:

```
List<Foo> test = new List<Foo>();
//...
List<Foo> test2 = test;
```

But as long as `test` and `test2` are two separate instances then modifications to one aren't reflected in the other.  Again, nor should they be.

---

If you *want* this behavior (modifications to one instance being reflected in another), then you'd likely have to create your own collection implementation.  Which shouldn't be terribly difficult.  Just create a custom class which inherits from `IList<T>`.  In the implementation of that class you could perhaps store the backing data for the collection in a `static` property.

I'm not sure what other side-effects that might have, since I've never heard of wanting this behavior before.  But at the very least a `static` member would reflect a change in all instances of the class.

Comment: I am trying to replace `test[0]` with a new object. Is this possible?

Comment: @gartenriese: Yes.  `test[0] = new Foo(3);`  The behavior you're *expecting* to happen simply isn't how object-oriented development works.  Modifying one instance of an object does not modify other instances of that same type.  As an analogy, consider two identical cars.  Same model, same year, same color, same everything.  If you put something into the trunk of one of those two cars, it won't *also* be in the trunk of the other car.  In your case, if you want non-standard behavior then you'll need to implement your own object.  (Your own `IList<T>`)

Comment: I'm coming from C++, so this is kind of new to me. With C++ I would have stored pointers in the array and I could have just let the pointer point to a new object, and I thought objects in C# behaved similar, so that's what I tried.

Comment: @gartenriese: In that case think of the variable names and the array indexes as your "pointers".  When you modify `test2[0]`, you are pointing it to a new instance.  The previous instance, which is still pointed to by `test[0]`, is unaffected.

Comment: So I can't do anything like look where the variable points to and replace that with something so the other variables that pointed there point to the new thing now too?

Comment: @gartenriese: Not that I'm aware of, at least not in managed code. And I'm honestly having trouble imagining a scenario where one really would want to do that. If you want to modify the object instance itself, that modification should be performed on that instance. You could maybe wrap your instance in some kind of `Func<>` which *resolves* to that instance, and then replace the instance at will since the `Func<>` will dynamically resolve to the new one? I'm not sure that would work, and I suspect it would be *ugly* and potentially buggy code.

Answer (score 0):

They are 2 different lists, 2 different instances, you cannot do it unless you do:

```
test2 = test
```

Can you please explain why you need it to be done the way you do it?